# Ephemeris data mismatch between Nasa Horizonz and Astro.com

Tags: ephemeris

I have tried to compare the Ephemeris data from Nasa's Horizons with ephemeris 
tables from astro.com. And they do not match. Example:

Date: 22th of July 2018. Body: Mars. Time 00:00 UT
Horizons: 309 degrees (Ephemeris type=Observer)
Astro.com: 305 degrees (http://www.astro.com/swisseph/ae/2000/ae_2018.pdf)

But some bodies are matching. Like Mercury and Saturn.

Am I doing something wrong?

Sources:
Nasa Horizons: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi#top

Astro.com: http://www.astro.com/swisseph/swepha_e.htm

Comment: astro-seek state that they get it from horizonz and theirs dont match either. Example: https://horoscopes.astro-seek.com/astrology-ephemeris-planetary-online-ephemerides

Comment: Astro-seek state that they get their data form Horizonz and theirs matches astro.com com, but not Horizonz (at least when I try to get it through Horizonz). Example: https://horoscopes.astro-seek.com/calculate-astrology-ephemeris-july-2018/?uzel_true=&lilith_true=&presnost=2&barva=p

Comment: What positions are you giving? I do not see 309 or 305 degrees in either set of data that you give. Actually, I have no idea what the astro.com site is giving. I need to consult an astrologer to know what they are giving, but I do not know any astrologers to ask.

Comment: Could you perhaps include some screenshots-- like @JohnHoltz I couldn't see 305 anywhere in your PDF file.

Comment: It is unclear what is being compared here. Normally at least 2 co-ordinate values such as Right Ascension, Declination or an Ecliptic longitude and latitude are needed to specify the position of anything

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because one of the two sites is non-scientific while the other is the preeminent site regarding the behavior of the solar system.

Comment: Astrology notation is archaic, but ecliptic longitude is ecliptic longitude. Voting to keep open.

Comment: You got my "leave open" vote, but with an edit suggestion to remove the astrology link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be comparing an [ecliptic longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecliptic_coordinate_system) to a [right ascension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equatorial_coordinate_system).
These are measured around different circles, the ecliptic and the equator respectively.
Their values coincide at the solstices ($\lambda$ 90$^\circ$ or 270$^\circ$, RA 6h or 18h) but generally not elsewhere.

With target body Mars, a geocentric observer location, and output quantities 2 (apparent RA & Dec) and 31 (observer ecliptic lon & lat) selected, JPL HORIZONS gives:

```
Date__(UT)__HR:MN     R.A.__(a-apparent)__DEC    ObsEcLon    ObsEcLat
2018-Jul-22 00:00     20 38 23.96 -24 58 44.6 305.5424192  -6.2964464
```

RA 20h 38m 24s is 309.60$^\circ$, but the quantity to compare is the ecliptic longitude, 305.54$^\circ$.

The Astrodienst ephemeris table, [based on JPL DE431](http://www.astro.com/swisseph/swephinfo_e.htm), gives ♒ 5$^\circ$ 33', i.e. ecliptic longitude 300$^\circ$ + 5.55$^\circ$ = 305.55$^\circ$, for Mars on 2018-07-22.

Comment: Yep, you are right, I thought that the RA DEC from Horizons was in the ecliptic plane - which is used in Astrology, but they are not. The 31 (observer ecliptic long & lan) is exactly what Im looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can compare the quantities more directly by selecting 'decimal degrees' under the 'angle format' when choosing the output quantities